# How can we make all the past dates in the calendar unselectable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I had a html5 calender of `type="datetime"`. I want the past dates to make unselectable.

```
<input  class="form-control" type="datetime" date-time auto-close="true" view="date"
datepicker-options="dateOptions" min-view="date" maxlength="10" format="dd/MM/yyyy" 
ng-model="$ctrl.DateInput" required="true">
```

[image]

All the dates inside the rectangle should be in disable state.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried `min="new Date()"`?

Answer (score 1):

With Javascript, you can set the `min` attribute of the date control. You can also set this from your ViewModal.

```js
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("date-control")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
```

```html
<input name="date-control" type="date">
```

Comment: Yes.. this is the exact fix ; https://recalll.co/app/?q=Disable%20certain%20dates%20from%20html5%20datepicker

Comment: Iam using angular js ..I cant use document.getElement by name..MOre over in my case,the calender is different as in scrrenshot ..how can i make that work in this case

Comment: Make your ng-model as an object and bind it to min attribute.

Comment: can u give an example for this case

Comment: @KishoreKumar in the above code we are not getting the calender displayed as the img i pasted..Is it possible for u to get the date picker to it wiorking with above functionality