# How to use on-change event for textfield to make it empty if min-date condition fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, meteor

I had an input field with type="datetime" where it has min-date condition as todays date.The flow is, if the date is valid,then submit button is enabled or else it will be in disabled state.Its working fine.

But now if the user selects the date which is invalid(old date),the date will be displayed in text box but the button will be disabled.

I want to use ng-change such that if user selects invalid date(old date),on-change event should make the text field as empty and want to display error message..How can we get this ng-change working

Html:

```
<input  class="form-control" type="datetime" date-time auto-close="true" view="date"
min-date="{{today}}" min-view="date" maxlength="10" format="dd/MM/yyyy" 
ng-model="$ctrl.newClient.DateInput" required="true" 
ng-change="$ctrl.checkdate">
```

controller:

```
$scope.today= new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
this.checkdate=function(){

};
```

Can someone help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-pikaday, it's easier to manage dates with this lib, so the user can select the date and you can manage it after the selection on a calendar. With pikaday you can set the min selectable date, so you can delete your checkdate function.
Read also [How can we make all the past dates in the calendar unselectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865383) . Maybe it's another solution :)

Comment: Ok..but this is the required functionality..can u help in this case

Answer (score 0):

A more user friendly solution is using [datetime-local](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdatetime-local%5D) and min attribute which does not let the user to select a date before that.

Example:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="exampleInput" name="input" 
       ng-model="example.value" min="2017-01-01T00:00:00" />
```

[Working Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qs7UsUCgNXqhuCN7yBy1?p=preview)

Comment: Ok..but this is the required functionality..can u help in this case